# Probability Dipkomsky survival

Tags: probability

Dipkomsky, a desperado in the wild West, is surrounded by an enemy gang and
fighting tooth and nail for his survival. He has m guns, m > 1, pointing in different directions and tries to use them in succession to give an impression that there are several defenders. When he turns to a subsequent gun and discovers that the gun is loaded he fires it with probability 1/2 and moves to the next one. Otherwise, i.e. when the gun is unloaded, he loads it with probability 3/4 or simply moves to the next gun with complementary probability 1/4. If he decides to load the gun he then fires it or not with probability 1/2 and after that moves to the next gun anyway.
Initially, each gun had been loaded independently with probability p. Show that if after each move this distribution is preserved, then p = 3/7. Calculate the expected value E[N] and variance Var[N] of the number N of loaded guns under this distribution.

This is Bernoulli trials and I can use binomial distribution?

Answer (score 0):

That the distribution is preserved means that the probability $p$ of encountering a loaded gun does not change after each move (''turn to the gun''). The probability of encountering a loaded gun *after* a move is equal to the probability of encountering a loaded gun and not firing from it + the probability of encountering an unloaded gun, loading it and then not firing from it. Namely,
\begin{align}
p=\frac{1}{2}p+(1-p)\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2},
\end{align}
whence $p=3/7$.

The number of loaded guns $N$ is binomially distributed, $N\sim Bin(m,p)$. Hence $E(N)=mp$, $V(N)=mp(1-p).$